# Get current working directory from Vte (GTK Terminal Widget) in Python

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, vte

Hey,
How can I get the current working directory of a VTE widget in Python?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowing from Mark, a slightly more elegant approach:

```
import vte
import os
v = vte.Terminal()
vPid = v.fork_command()
workingDir = os.readlink('/proc/%s/cwd' % vPid)
```

Comment: Will check this in the morning and see if it works, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kludge, but the best way I can think of would be:

```
import vte
import os
v = vte.Terminal()
vPid = v.fork_command()
# make a system call to pwdx to get working director
sIn, sOut = os.popen2("pwdx " + vPid)
workingDir = sOut.read()
```